# KeyListener doesn't produce any response

Tags: java, awt, listener, keylistener

Given the following (partial) code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Test extends Applet implements MouseListener , KeyListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int TOTAL_POINTS = 500;
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 5;

    // the arrays that contain the indexes of the points that the user created 
    private int[] m_Xindex, m_yIndex;  

    // The number of points that the user created 
    private int m_pointsCreated;       

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) 
    {
          char key = keyEvent.getKeyChar();
          if (key == 'F')
              System.out.println("123");
    } 

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {/* Empty */ }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {/* Empty */ }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {/* Empty */ }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {/* Empty */ }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent myEvent) {/* Empty */ }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent)  {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {}
}
```

I removed my working code and left only the problematic code.

When I press `F` , I want to print to the screen `123` , but nothing is 
printed to the screen.

What's wrong with the code of `keyTyped`?

Comment: Also, don't forget to register the key listener. Also beware that key listeners will only work if the component it is registered to is focusable and has current focus.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Make it an answer so I'll pick it as the right one , since you've just made my day ! +1 !!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change if `(key == 'F')` to `if (key.equals('F'))`.  Test for object equivalence rather than equality.
2. Be sure that the component is `focusable` & to `requestFocusInWindow()`.   The latter should best be done by an `@Override` on the `start()` method.
3. Consider using Swing (`JApplet`) and key bindings instead of AWT `Applet` and `KeyListener`.